# Leaflet map won't render in browser

Tags: html, r, leaflet, r-markdown

I have a map using Leaflet which works in the html output of r markdown, but the map won't render when I open the html in Google or IE. Ggmap works fine, but I'd prefer an interactive map. Any ideas?

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  echo = FALSE,
  warning = FALSE,
  message = FALSE,
  comment=NA,
  fig.height=7,
  fig.width = 9)
```

```{r Libraries}
library(leaflet)
library(ggmap)
```

Plot map with leaflet package.    
```{r Leaflet}
#using leaflet
Pin <- data.frame(t(c(ID=1,Lat=-27.474176,Lng=153.024901)))

Bne2 <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles()  %>%
  addMarkers(data=Pin)
Bne2

```

Plot map with ggmap package.   
```{r Ggmap}
#using ggmap
Sa2 <- data.frame(t(c(ID=1,Lat=-27.474176,Lng=153.024901)))
Brisbane <- get_map("Brisbane,Australia",zoom=11)

BNE <- ggmap(Brisbane)+
  geom_point(data=Sa2,aes(x=Lng,y=Lat),color="black",size=3)

plot(BNE)

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing the same issue, and it appears to be related to the default tiles not rendering in the browser. But, I have no idea why that's the case.

So a couple of options are

1. Change the tile layer (https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-providers/preview/)
2. Use a different mapping package. Here I'm demonstrating my googleway package for plotting interactive Google Maps

---

````
```{r Libraries}
library(leaflet)
library(ggmap)
library(googleway)
```

Plot map with leaflet package.    
```{r Leaflet}
#using leaflet
Pin <- data.frame(t(c(ID=1,Lat=-27.474176,Lng=153.024901)))

Bne2 <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles(urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')  %>%
  addMarkers(data=Pin)
Bne2

```

Plot map with ggmap package.   
```{r Ggmap}
#using ggmap
Sa2 <- data.frame(t(c(ID=1,Lat=-27.474176,Lng=153.024901)))
Brisbane <- get_map("Brisbane,Australia",zoom=11)

BNE <- ggmap(Brisbane)+
  geom_point(data=Sa2,aes(x=Lng,y=Lat),color="black",size=3)

plot(BNE)

```

Plot map with googleway
```{r googleway}
## you need an api key to use google maps
mapKey <- 'your_api_key'

google_map(key = mapKey) %>%
    add_markers(data = Pin)

```
````

Here are all three working in Chrome

[image]

Comment: Thanks, googleway looks very thorough so change packages

Comment: @Zeus - thanks! there are some known limitations with it though (such as no legend), but if you have any comments or feedback let me know through the [issues page on github](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues)

Comment: I've installed the package, loaded the library and now have an api key, but R can't find the function google_map? Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @Zeus are you sure you've loaded the library?

Comment: yes, its bizarre. R can see functions google_prediction, google_distance etc but no google_map. I've reinstalled the package and no errors loading the library

Comment: `google_prediction` isn't one of mine. Try restarting R too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148272/discussion-between-zeus-and-symbolixau).